# how to resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, exception, jersey, out-of-memory, twilio

is this issue related to tomcat max/min heap size?

if I increase the java heap size in tomcat config will resolve this?

> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse
>   mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The exception contained within
>   MappableContainerException  could not be mapped to a response,
>   re-throwing to the HTTP container java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:215)
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:145)
>   at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:154)
>   at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:91)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(URLJarFile.java:93)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
>   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)

I have tomcat-7.0.63 and Java 1.7 installed on Linux-os(32bit),
 
I updated the Twilio library to latest one recently, does it causing any memory leak?

Comment: Information you shared is not enough. It’s important to spot root cause of your issue. Please note that when there is lack of RAM an application can fail with OOM error in any place, even in printing to the log.

Comment: For me the ZIP file you are trying to open, is very big. Incresing the JVM size could solve this problem.

Comment: What is the message of `OutOfMemoryError`? It could be memory or system limits and the error message tells which.

Answer (score 0):

`OutOfMemoryError` is used to report different problems e.g. heap space exhaustion, GC CPU threshold reached, file descriptors exhaustion, et.c The message after the error tells what is the actual problem.

Since your stack trace starts with `java.util.zip.ZipFile.open()` it's most likely the file descriptor exhaustion. Since you are on Linux you should check [`ulimit -a`](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-ulimit.html) and see if your limit is acceptable. Either:

1. Increase the limits if your application requires higher limitis
2. Check that application correctly closes resources, perhaps there is a bug in your code.